# Searching and conversion of files(batch processing) using .vb script and Ironpython

Tags: file, vbscript, ironpython, directory, file-extension

I have to convert large number of files from one format(.DAT) to another format(.CSV) using a software.The software follows COM(Component Object Model), there is a in-process interface available in it to do the scripting using either VBS(Visual Basic Scripts) or Iron python. 
Here is the idea of it.

1. Search in each sub folder for the files with .DAT extension
2. get the filepath of .DAT file found and pass it to converter.
3. converter converts it and saves it with same name but with the .csv format in a    different folder

**Problem:**
Now I have these .DAT files located in a different sub folders in a folder. How do I repeat(looping) the task of searching for these files(.DAT files), pass it to the converter, convert them and save it to other location with same name but with different file extension(.CSV).

How to get the filepath of the file with .DAT extension and pass it to the converter?

Here is the code I gathered and pieced up together to search for .DAT files in each folder.

```
 'On Error Resume Next
TraverseFolders objFso.GetFolder("E:\Austausch Move About")

Function TraverseFolders(fldr)
  ' do stuff with the files in fldr here, or ...

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    TraverseFolders sf  '<- recurse here
       For Each objFile In sf.Files
        If UCase(objFile.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "DAT" Then
         Next

  ' ... do stuff with the files in fldr here.

End Function
```

Here is the code I am using for conversion

```
`
Dim CSVPath 
Dim dataPath
Dim dataFile
CSVPath = "C:\Temp\Trail4.csv"
dataPath = UserSettings.UserDirectoryStorage
dataFile  = "E:\Austausch Move About\MEA_0072\DO020072.DAT"
Dim workspace
Set workspace = AnalysisWorkspace
Dim config
Set config = workspace.DataPool
' Previously loaded measurement data will be removed first
 config.Reset( )
' Load the data file
config.ImportData(dataFile)
' Test if the data file could be sucessfully loaded
If(config.DataGroups.Count > 0) Then
  myMsg = MsgBox("The file '"+dataFile+"' was loaded.",0,"IPEmotion")
Else
  myMsg = MsgBox("The file '"+dataFile+"' could not be loaded!",0,"IPEmotion")
End If 

Dim CSV
CSV= "CSV"
config.ExportData CSVPath, CSV
GraphicalUserInterface.VisibleView = 4
GraphicalUserInterface.VisibleView = 6
GraphicalUserInterface.VisibleView = 4
GraphicalUserInterface.VisibleView = 6
GraphicalUserInterface.VisibleView = 4
GraphicalUserInterface.VisibleView = 8
GraphicalUserInterface.VisibleView = 6
GraphicalUserInterface.WindowState = 1
GraphicalUserInterface.WindowState = 2
GraphicalUserInterface.WindowState = 1
GraphicalUserInterface.WindowState = 2
GraphicalUserInterface.WindowState = 1
GraphicalUserInterface.WindowState = 2
GraphicalUserInterface.WindowState = 1
GraphicalUserInterface.WindowState = 2
`
```

Is there any other alternative that could solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative to a(ny) recursive directory walker (rdw) is to shell out to `dir /s /b "w:\here\ever\*.dat"`.

The alternative to the structure/layout of your rdw is something like this:

```
Function TraverseFolders(fldr)
  For Each f In fldr.Files 
      ProcessFile f ' contrains .dat filter
  Next
  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    TraverseFolders sf
  Next
End Function
```

which separates looping and file processing more clearly and at least looks like tail recursion.

**Update wrt added question** (How to get the filepath of the file with .DAT extension and pass it to the converter?):

When looping over the (file) objects in the .Files collection, use their .Path property:

```
>> For Each oFile In goFS.GetFolder(".\").Files
>>     WScript.Echo oFile.Path
>> Next
>>
...
C:\Documents and Settings\eh\00.head
C:\Documents and Settings\eh\00.hta
...
```